# Attempting to access RAM /dev/mem... says "Operation not permitted"

Tags: linux, memory, dd, hexdump

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

I read the following tutorial on how to access the contents of RAM in Linux....

http://www.rootninja.com/using-dd-to-search-for-strings-in-memory-or-devices/

Code:

`dd if=/dev/mem | hexdump -C | grep “string to search for”`

So, I run the code...

Code:

`sudo dd if=/dev/mem | hexdump -C > NAMEOFOUTPUTFILEHERE.txt`

And... it starts pumping out HEX code, until a few seconds later, where it says:

```
dd: reading `/dev/mem': Operation not permitted
2056+0 records in 
2056+0 records out
1052672 bytes (1.1 MB) copied, 0.44834 s, 2.3 MB/s
```

So basically.. I am able to get about 3.3 MB of RAM dump contents-- until the program stops, saying "Operation not permitted"

And so I am wondering why am I not able to dump the entire contents of RAM? Is this a deliberate limitation in Ubuntu, to stop malicious hackers? Or, is it something else? Does anybody know? Thanks

Comment: OK... forget it... turns out Ubuntu has 1 MB limit on RAM extraction, as defined in the kernel.. and obviously, that's good security, because then a hacker can't extract your passwords from RAM etc...

And so... yeah.... this thread is now SOLVED

Here is the full info, for anyone interested....

Comment: if your kernel was compiled with STRICT_DEVMEM=y (see e.g. /boot/config-KERNELVERSION) then only the first 1MB is read from /dev/mem . This isn’t so much a kernel version issue, as a result of how your own machine’s kernel was compiled; most distro kernels will have this restriction in place for good reason.

You can download and insmod the forensic kernel module fmem to work around this; at your own risk! rmmod it as soon as possible afterwards. The fmem module provides a /dev/fmem device without any security restrictions.

Comment: " am able to get about 3.3 MB of RAM dump contents-". Uhm, you are?  All I see is `1052672 bytes (1.1 MB) copied`. Not 3.3MB (nor 2.3MB/sec which was a speed).

Answer (score 6):

The linux kernel on your Ubuntu installation ships with has a setting<sup>*</sup> which limits RAM extraction to has 1 MB.

If you do not wish that you can either recompile the kernel without it (obvious caveeat: you are lowering security!) or you can download and insmod the forensic kernel module fmem to work around this. That provides a /dev/fmem device without any security.

As mentioned by Opello: you can also use `strict-devmem=0` in the kernel cmdline.

---

<sup>*</sup>: `STRICT_DEVMEM=y` (see e.g. /boot/config-KERNELVERSION)

Comment: You can also pass `strict-devmem=0` in the kernel cmdline.

Comment: Only on [Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=492803#c1) and related distros, if \*even\* this day